# Postgres SQL function string_to_array

Tags: arrays, function, postgresql

I have a table:

```
   c1|c2|c3|c4
-----+--+--+----    
    a  b c  10
    a  a b  20
    c  a c  10
    b  b c  10
    c  b c  30
```

I want to write a function where the inputs are 3 strings / text eg ('**a b c**, **b d**, **c**'), compare every element to each other, find if a row exist with this combination, an sum the number of the 4th (**c4**) column up. But if there is a constellation of **b a c** or **c a b**  it would match **a b c 10**. If there is a row like **b c c** then it wont be a row like **c b b**. Every matchup is unique.

I think the best would be to use string_to_array(text, text).

I put together some pseudo code, but no idea how to write it in SQL. Maybe the logic is wrong too.

```
function (x,y,z)
 res = 0
 x_array = string_to_array(x, ' ')
 y_array = string_to_array(y, ' ')
 z_array = string_to_array(z, ' ')

 foreach(x_item in x_array)
  foreach(y_item in y_array)
   foreach(z_item in z_array)
    if  (c1 = (x_item || y_item || z_item ) && c2 = (x_item || y_item || z_item ) && c3 = (x_item || y_item || z_item ))
     res++
```

***EDIT***

- First off all there was a mistake in the example table. There was  a row **a b c** and **c b a**. It cant be. **a b c = c b a** ! and each row must be unique.
- example: three *text* inputs  **a b c** | **b c** | **c**
- each element vs each element: a b c , a c c, b b c, b c c, c b c, c c c
- **a b c** = 10;
  **a c c** (is the same as **c a c**) = 10;
  **b b c** = 10;
  **b c c** (is the same as **c b c**) = 30;
  **c b c** = 30;
  **c c c** (no match) = 0; result = **90**

Comment: Can you clarify your text? It seems contradictory to me. Especially make clear what your result should look like. Add an example.

Comment: new user tip: if you find some answer helpful/useful, you may want to accept/upvote it.

Answer (score 3):

I *think* this might be what you want:

*Return the sum of column `c4` from all rows where a given set of three tokens matches the columns `(c1, c2, c3)`.*

#### Simple version

Much simpler with [contains **`@>`** and is contained **`<@`** by operators](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-array.html):

```
SELECT sum(c4) AS sum_of_matching_c4
FROM   tbl
WHERE  ARRAY[c1,c2,c3] <@ ARRAY['b', 'a', 'c'] -- strings in arbitrary order
AND    ARRAY[c1,c2,c3] @> ARRAY['b', 'a', 'c'];
```

Sorry, that would fail for `('b', 'c', 'c')` vs. `('c', 'b', 'b')`.

#### Slow and sure

```
WITH i(arr) AS (
   SELECT ARRAY(VALUES ('b'), ('c'), ('c') ORDER BY 1)  -- input once
   )                                                    -- in arbitrary order
SELECT sum(c4) AS sum_of_matching_c4
FROM  (
  SELECT c4, array_agg(x ORDER BY x) AS arr
  FROM  (
      SELECT ctid, c4, unnest(ARRAY[c1,c2,c3]) AS x
      FROM   tbl t, i
      WHERE  ARRAY[c1,c2,c3] <@ arr -- optional pre-selection
      AND    ARRAY[c1,c2,c3] @> arr -- for better performance?
      ) a
   GROUP BY ctid, c4
   ) b
JOIN i USING (arr)
```

[-> sqlfiddle demo.](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!12/a81ff/11)

The major difficulty is to order the values of the columns *within* the row.

For your input (3 strings) I achieve this in the `WHERE` clause with a `VALUE` expression in the [CTE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-with.html) which I order right away and collect it in an array. I use a CTE for convenience, so we have to enter values in one place only.

It's more complicated for the row values. I put the three columns in an array and break that up to rows with [`unnest()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-array.html#ARRAY-FUNCTIONS-TABLE). As you did not provide a primary key, I use the [`ctid`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/ddl-system-columns.html) as ad-hoc surrogate primary key instead - which I need for the `GROUP BY` to stuff the now sorted `(c1, c2, c3)` into an array.

Finally I sum up all `c4` of rows where the now sorted arrays match exactly.

Note: I expressly do *not* use `string_agg()` because that does *not* produce distinct results. Consider:

```
'abc' 'cde' 'fgh'
'ab' 'ccdef' 'gh'
```

.. resulting int the same string if concatenated.

#### Index / Performance

You might consider to save pre-ordered data to speed up queries. Doing it on the fly is expensive. I.e. you could pre-generate the sorted array and save it as redundant column which you can then support with an index. Should be faster by several orders of magnitude for the cost of redundant data storage.
If you are dealing with *long strings*, a solution similar to what I outlined in this [related answer on dba.SE](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/25140/3684) might be the best course of action.

Alternatively (preferred!) guarantee that `(c1, c2, c3)` are always stored in ascending order. You could use a trigger `BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE` to keep values within the row ordered. No redundant storage and you can simply create a [multi-column index](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/indexes-multicolumn.html) on the three columns and compare to them one by one (instead of comparing the array like in my example).

Comment: _You might consider to save pre-ordered data to speed up queries._ can u explain it this more? what would you save in this example.? unfortunately the table has already 1 million unique rows.

Comment: @user1748124: I added a bit to my answer about pre-ordering data and indexing.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to write a function for that.

First, there's no "strings" with postgresql ( sql ) , it's "text" or "varchar".

Second, what you need is an SQL query like this:

```
SELECT ( DISTINCT ( c1 || c2 || c3 )) AS txtcol, SUM (c4) AS rowsum;
```

or

```
SELECT ( DISTINCT ( c1 || c2 || c3 )) AS txtcol, SUM(c4) AS numsum GROUP BY txtcol;
```

Can't recall the exact syntax at the moment, you need to work it out,
anyway the point is you need to concatenate varchar columns with some built-in
function like CONCAT or "||" operator, and then sum/group by numeric column. All you need
is to concatenate columns, and give resulting all-together column a name.
To be exact, you don't even need to show concatenated column on resulting table,
you could output just sums, and number of rows sumarized for example.

Theoretically you could write SQL function or PL/SQL function for that, but I'm sure it's just not necessary, your case seems to me simple enough to be able to achieve result you want without a function. Built-in sumarizing function SUM() is called "aggregate" function, other examples of aggregating functions are e.g. MIN() or MAX().
Note what you're actually trying to do, is grouping rows by some resulting VARCHAR column by the effect of concatenation per-row.

EDIT: "Arrays" in SQL or procedural SQL is some internally-handled arrays, do not confuse them with relations ( tables in database, nor with tables as SELECT results ). I think you also don't need SQL arrays for that, the task really isn't so hard as it looks like.